# obtaining a list of values from a POST using Flask

Tags: python, post, flask

Using Flask, I'm trying to create a simple list of values POSTed from a web page.  The only POSTed data will be the values associated with 1 to as many as 60 checkboxes, all named "state". The following code only returns the first value in the list, but all values are required for further processing:

```
.@app.route('/doCheck', methods = ['POST']) 
def doCheck():    
    d = request.form['state']
```

I tried using the method .getList() like so:

```
    d = request.form.getList('state')
    return d
```

...but get this error:  AttributeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object has no attribute 'getList'

So I tried this instead:

```
    d = getList(request.form)
    return d
```

...and got the error NameError: name 'getList' is not defined.

That seems to indicate I should include a method or class but which one?

Answer (score 13):

The method is [`getlist`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist), without a capital L:

```
states = request.form.getlist('state')
```